# Add image to taxonomy terms menu item

Tags: taxonomy-terms

My menu block is using the module: taxonomy menu terms to construct the main menu as a block to display in frontend.

I want to add image to each menu item, anyone know what is the simplest way to do that? or other module can do the same things?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Menu Icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_icons)? It is useful. 
If you want to add some custom image to every term, add the field into your entity and upload default image. But I think, this module works better.